# How to show a .svg file which is loaded in a variable on a html page (Blazor ServerSide)?

Tags: c#, svg, memory, load, blazor

I load a .svg file into a string edit that string. And now I want to display that edited string/.svg on the html page from my blazor project.

In windows forms I used

```
         //now show that svg icon in a picturebox (nuget 
         //https://github.com/vvvv/SVG)
         //input= the edit .svg String
         var mySvg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(input);
         PicbxShow.Image = mySvg.Draw(120,120);
```

If thought I use it in blazor like this:

```
<img src=@mySvg.Draw(240,240) />
```

or directly like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">@input</svg>
```

But the graphic is not shown. If I load it from file

```
<img src="/images/TEST.svg" />
```

it works but I don't want to load->edit->save->load(edited)->display.

How do I display a .svg that is in my variable mySvg

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"TEST.svg");
    input = reader.ReadToEnd();
    mySvg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(input);
```

I don't have to use the nuget (svg) if there is an other solution.
Thank you for your Help and Time

---

new tries

in the end I want to edit text "PHALT" in an .svg file and change that with other text (in blazor). And then display the icon with the updated text.
I tried this now but still cant get it to work:

```
@page "/"
@using System.IO;

@* Load file  -> ICON is shown *@
<img src="/images/_temp_circle.svg" />
<br />

@* Open file _temp_circle.svg and copy the .svh text to blazor page manualy-> 
 ICON is shown *@

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="7cm" width="7cm" 
 viewBox="00264.567 264.567"><g transform="matrix(3.77953 0 0 3.77953 
 -370.783 -731.84)"><circle cx="133.103" cy="228.633" r="24.892" 
  fill="#fff6d5" stroke="#a80" 
  stroke-width="2.074" stroke-linecap="round" />
 <path d="M133.103 208.228a3.058 3.058 0 00-3.065 3.065v23.567a7.42 7.42 0 
  00-4.355 6.757 7.42 7.42 0 007.42 7.42 7.42 7.42 0 007.42-7.42 7.42 7.420 
  00-4.355-6.757v-23.567a3.058 3.058 0 00-3.065-3.065z" opacity=".7" 
  fill="teal" stroke="#917c6f" stroke-width="1.219" stroke-linecap="square" 
  stroke-linejoin="round" />
  <text style="line-height:1.25;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif 
  Bold'" x="111.943" y="233.039" font-weight="700" font-size="19.121" font- 
  family="sans-serif" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#c8beb7" 
  stroke="#000" stroke-width=".695">
  <tspan x="111.943" y="233.039" style="-inkscape-font- 
   specification:'sans-serif Bold'">PHALT</tspan>
  </text></g></svg>
  <br />

  @* Read the svg file via stringreader and output the string here ->ICON 
     is NOT shown BUT the svg text is displayed as text WHY??? *@

 @input
 <br />

  <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="LoadSvg">Click me</button>
```

@code{

```
  string path = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\images\"}";
  string input;


  private void LoadSvg()
  {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path + @"_temp_circle.svg");
    input = reader.ReadToEnd();

    input = input.Replace("PHALT", "TEST");
    reader.Close();
 }

}
```

Comment: SVG is xml format.  Using Serialization is slow which is what SvgDocument.FromSvg is doing.   You can parse the SVG using Xml Linq which will be faster and you could put the URL path into a dictionary to speed up getting the URL.

Comment: @jdweng Thx for the hint. Could you explain a little more what you mean :). Okay I got the parse part with Linq but what is the URL path ? I got the file localy on my hd on the server?  Besides that my main problem is that I cant get that .svg displayed from memory do you know how you could do that. Thanks anyway for the repley

Comment: The URL could also be a filename.  What needs to be displayed?  There are SVG viewer sthat you can find on web.

Comment: Why not use `MarkupString`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#raw-html

Comment: @Nechemia Hoffmann finaly something that  looks simple and works ...  Thank you so much. The idea of MarkupString is working. I dont no if that is the best way ... but is does the job. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could render an image in `HTML` from `base64` string like this:

`<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,gdmVy...your-svg-bytes-as-base64-data-here.."/>`

or similar but with another content type if you do that for a rasterized bitmap image.

Comment: Thank you for you input. Iam in no way good at blazer c# etc. I would say that the answere from @Nechemia Hoffmann is the one that did what I wanted to do. I dont know the pros and cons. But for other visiters check out the idea of MarkupString as in the comments above

Comment: This kind of thinking is very bad for our time of microservices. If you have a TINY image this is a good cheat.. If you have any modern HD image, your base64 string could be in the megabytes, you will also burn CPU cycles encoding and decoding that huge string.. Also you may crash a browser or two by trying to send a 2MB image as a text string. You should do as @BennyBoy1973 suggest or send your SVG string directly to the dom with JSInterop, or use svg.js on client side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the way you're trying to handle .svg will be the easiest in Blazor.  You can use <svg> tags (i.e. entire contents of any svg file) anywhere you would put <div> or other HTML tags in a Blazor component.

Then you can use @variable wherever you want to change or add any components, and add @code{} to change whatever you want, just like any other Blazor component.  So:

(MySVGComponent.Blazor)

```
<svg blah blah blah>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#0074d9"
        stroke-width="2" points="@PointString" />
</svg>
@code {
     public string @PointString {get;set;}
     public void AddPoint (int X, int Y){
        @PointString += " " + X + "," + Y;
}
```